# Permissions issues with publishing Google Sheets worksheets on Google Sites

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, google-sites

I have a Google spreadsheet comprising of several worksheets and I am trying to publish the worksheets individually on separate webpages, preferably using embed. This is to provide access to users within a Google Workspace domain. The first published worksheet works fine and is duly visible to users allowed to view the Google Sites webpage. Subsequent worksheets are also published successfully but the previously published worksheets are no longer accessible. I get the following message:

> "*You need permission to access this published document.
> You are signed in as ****@***.org.uk, but you don't have permission to access this published document. You may need to sign in as a different user.* "

The above email address is an editor of the spreadsheet as well as being able to edit/view the Google Sites. I have tried everything by only using Incognito windows only, logging out of all accounts, checked settings, etc: I am always unable to publish more than one worksheet from the same spreadsheet at a time.

What am I doing wrong???

#### PS-1:

Following iansedan suggestion I have anonymised and simplified the spreadsheet. There are 2 tabs I want to publish to web: **Group T** and **Group S**.

- I publish **Group T** to the web: works as expected in the browser (Chrome).
- I publish **Group S** to the web and view it in another tab in the browser (Chrome)

It duly shows the published version of Group S but when I click on the other tab (to view the Group T which was OK before) I get the following message:

> *"You need permission to access this published document.
> You are signed in as [my workspace email address], but you don't have permission to access this published document. You may need to sign in as a different user."*

This is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8GIZC--qSBLFUP125A6vzoS9EuOqbA_OJPdwh95yJ0/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet. I'm afraid I don't know how to share this better, the only way I could find is if you try to access the spreadsheet I will get a notification and will add your email address so you can view/edit it.

#### PS-2 Additional info

The respective links for the published are as follows:

[Group T](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vROttnpnQ0HP5FkBKTQoaYyjIzOmg_nf2jWz84q_mkivNdi6xs5yR8Sb-5oO468XqxMMFlO7yNBYKmC/pubhtml?gid=652115792&single=true) This one comes up with the "You need permission to access this published document." message

[Group S](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vROttnpnQ0HP5FkBKTQoaYyjIzOmg_nf2jWz84q_mkivNdi6xs5yR8Sb-5oO468XqxMMFlO7yNBYKmC/pubhtml?gid=1897367352&single=true) This one shows the published worksheet correctly (as it was the last published!).

It looks like a caching mechanism somewhere is causing the issue but I have no idea where and how to prevent it! I've cleared the cache in the browser...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you provide reproduction steps? See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you, I will attempt to do just this, who knows maybe following the advice in the link above will help me sove the issue!!

Comment: Can you please share your document publicly? You go to share > get link and set the spreadsheet viewable to "anyone with link". Also, can you give some context as to what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe there is another way...

Comment: Here's the link to the document:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8GIZC--qSBLFUP125A6vzoS9EuOqbA_OJPdwh95yJ0/edit?usp=sharing. I am trying to publish Group T on its own in a Google Sites webpage (using the embed code) and Group S in a separate webpage (in the same Google Sites). As explained before only the last published page works. In the live system the respective Group T and Group S pages are viewable by different groups. This is all within the same Workspace account.

Comment: Here's the link to the associated test website: https://sites.google.com/sagns.org.uk/testwebsite/home. Group S is the last published page and works. Group T was published immediately before, worked then but does not  work since Group S has been published.

Comment: I just tried, 1. new sheet 2. get embed HTML for sheet1 and then HTML for sheet2. 3. put them both into an html file and ran on a local server. It worked fine... So not sure what is going on. Maybe you are signed into multiple accounts? Try from an incognito session. Also, where are you trying to enforce the restriction between the groups? At the spreadsheet level or the site level? I think the simplest solution might be to use different sheets.

Answer (score 0):

To publish individual sheets of a spreadsheet, use the Published Content and Settings button instead of the Publish button.
Uncheck the All Document checkbox and select the Group T and Group S sheets. After that click Escape and Start Publishing.

[image]

Comment: Group T and Group S need to be published separately (as the viewers of these worksheets belong to different groups). Following the steps as per above for just the Group T worksheet produces the expected result (ie its associated web page correctly display the published worksheet). Going through the same process for just the Group S after also produces the right reult (ie the associated webpage display the published version of Group S), but if I then refresh the previously working webpage for the published Group T I get the permission issue and the worksheet is not displayed any more. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

What youre doing is pausing one publication to start another one. Then, the first one is canceled.

Basically, there are two fields on the web publishing tab: one above another.

On the upper one, you chosse wich part of your sheet you will publish. That is, here if Jonh need to see "X", you select "X" and take note of the link to send to John.

On the lower one, you confirm all parts of the sheet that are being published at til that time. In other words, there will be more than one part in this fild. That is, if you havd alredy done the process to John (X), Anna (Y) and Floyd (Z), you will visualize X, Y and Z

Got it?